# Python Cython generated Executable shows import error

Tags: python, gcc, cython, importerror

I recently learned how to compile cython to exe , I am trying to compile a simple gui practice script (I'm a newbie)

```
import sys,os
import msvcrt,Image,ImageTk
import Tkinter as Tk
import ttk,io,subprocess
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(),os.O_BINARY)
#data=sys.stdin.read()
def callback():
    contrast=subprocess.Popen('conv out.jpg -brightness-contrast 30x10 -resize 350x PNG:-',shell=1,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    contrast=io.BytesIO(contrast)
    photo=Image.open(contrast).copy().resize((350,350))
    preview.imo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
    preview.config(image=preview.imo)
m=Tk.Tk()
#conv mkchoice.jpg -brightness-contrast 10x30 out.jpg
m.title('Editor')
op=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('mkchoice.jpg').resize((350,350)))
original=Tk.Label(m,text="Original",image=op)
original.pack()
preview=Tk.Label(m,text="Preview",image=op)
preview.pack(side='left')
button=ttk.Button(m,text="Contrast",command=callback)
button.pack()
m.mainloop()
```

The script compiles to exe just fine fine but exe gives an import error upon execution

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "std.py", line 16, in init std (std.c:1518)
    op=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('mkchoice.jpg').resize((350,350)))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1290, in resize
    self.load()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 164, in load
    self.load_prepare()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 231, in load_prepare

    self.im = Image.core.new(self.mode, self.size)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 37, in __getattr__
    raise ImportError("The _imaging C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed
```

I think it needs the _imaging.pyd file from PIL directory but I don't know how to include it

My `gcc` command ATM is

```
gcc %gcp% %out:.py=.c% -I"C:\python\include" -L"C:\Python\libs" -lpython27 -o %out:.py=%.exe
```

Comment: It might well be an issue with GCC vs Microsoft Visual C (they don't mix very well where Python is concerned, and typically Python is build with Visual C on Windows). You can get a copy of the necessary bits of the Visual C compiler from microsoft - http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Comment: I can't give you much advice on how to use it though, and it's always possible that isn't the problem and you'll just waste your time trying to work out Visual C.

Comment: Also, you have made sure that the script runs in Python before trying to compile it, right?

Comment: @DavidW i don't understand . How can an import error be caused by bad compiler . i've been able to compile simple scripts using gcc successfully . scripts that use other python modules e.g re , urllib2 , only this one gives error and i don't know how to tell it to use _imaging.pyd file

Comment: @DavidW yup it works in python only exe shows the error given in question

Comment: It's trying to use a module written in C, rather than one written in Python (I think the others you've tried are all pure Python). If that has been compiled in a way that isn't compatible with gcc, it could be your problem. However - it's a guess so I could be completely wrong.

Comment: (That said, you look to manage to import Tkinter without errors, so perhaps that isn't the issue)

Comment: I suppose a better question would be "how to tell cython that the library requires _imaging.pyd file

Comment: Can I suggest one further thing to try: use the more up-to-date Pillow imaging library (which is based on PIL) rather than PIL (which hasn't been updated since 2011 or so). You have to change the exact imports but otherwise they're pretty compatible. It isn't obvious whether it will fix your problem, but even if it doesn't it should give you a clearer error message (I think PIL hides the import errors from _imaging until you try to use it, and so loses the context).

Comment: @DavidW Right i will update to Pillow , i doubt it'd solve the problem though .. i guess there's no way for me to link to that _imaging.pyd except using other freezing methods which will give me enormous exe sizes .. Thank you for being so nice though :) i really appreciate it